# Adding an index to a Derby database table

Tags: indexing, relational-database, derby

Although I don't think it matters the type of database whose table you are adding an index to, do you think I would have to update the index when I am adding records into the table? I plan on adding an index to the ID column of a table, and do not know if I would have to programmatically update this index when I add a new record to the table.

Comment: What do you mean, "I don't think it matters"? Why don't you think it matters? What is your justfication? What has your research shown? What does the manual say? See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts re researching before asking. PS "I don't think X" (ie "I think not-X") typically means the opposite--"it is not the case that I think not-X"--intended to give the false impression that one is absolved from researching because one has already researched enough to have an opinion--while protecting oneself by expressing doubt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indexes are automatically recalculated when an insert happens, Derby is no exception in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a little extra info, I was just wondering the same thing, and found this in the Derby docs ([Tuning Java DB](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.10.1.2/tuning/ctundepth1003116.html) ):

> ... over time, index pages fragment. Rebuilding indexes improves performance significantly in these situations. To rebuild an index, drop it and then re-create it.